# Package installation in Termux

Tags: installation, terminal, command-line, file-permissions, termux

I'm reading this guide that describes how to [install the statistical language R on Termux](https://conr.ca/post/installing-r-on-android-via-termux/). My installation journey is briefly outlined below.

> I need to determine why nothing happens at Step #2 below. Anybody have an idea?

#### Step 1: Add the [its-pointless](https://github.com/its-pointless) package repository

*I copy/paste the following text to Termux, hit enter, and the console spits confirmation text, and it appears everything works fine.*

```
pkg install curl gnupg
mkdir -p "$PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list.d/"
echo "deb https://its-pointless.github.io/files/ termux extras" > "$PREFIX/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pointless.list"
curl "https://its-pointless.github.io/pointless.gpg" | apt-key add
```

#### Step 2: Install required .deb packages

*I then copy/paste the following code block to Termux, hit Enter on the keyboard, and nothing is output to the console. It appears nothing has happened. I try to copy/paste each line individually, `pkg install r-base` then `pkg install make`, etc., but nothing is output to the console and nothing happens.*

```
pkg install r-base \
            make \
            clang \
            gcc-7 \
            libgfortran \
            openssl-dev \
            libcurl-dev \
            libicu-dev \
            libxml2-dev
```

#### Step 3: Configure your compiler with [its-pointless](https://github.com/its-pointless) script

If I can make it this far I'll simply copy/paste the following directly into Termux.

```
setupclang-gfort-8
```

#### Step 4-6: [...see the rest of the guide if you wish](https://conr.ca/post/installing-r-on-android-via-termux/)

---

So yeah, I need to figure why nothing happens at step #2 and I can't proceed any further with the install. Maybe I need to change directories at some point? Funny enough, even when I did a basic command such as `ls` nothing was printed to my console. Is there some permissions I need to change?

Comment: Are you sure are connected to internet (use ping)? Did you try "apt install" or "apt update" or reinstalling Termux?

Comment: I was using a demo unit at BestBuy. Now that I think about it, the demo software probably prevents this type of thing??? Although I was able to install Termux from the play store. It surprised me I was able to install stuff on a demo unit.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with demo package or whatever language you are trying to install. I know about general usage problems of Termux or Linux package managers.